# Batch Powershell, Downloading a file from a url only results in part of the file?

Tags: windows, powershell

Alright so I'm new-ish to the whole powershell thing and was figuring out how I could download a file via powershell activated via a batch file.

my current code is basically this

```
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.dropbox.com/s/**********/tester.exe','tester.exe')
```

so, the first time I ran this as a .bat file, It worked perfectly, the file downloaded fully and ran properly when executed.

However I deleted the file off my pc, ran the .bat again and got back only a portion of the download, e.g. Original file -350 KB ---  Downloaded file 209 KB

Because of this the file would not run, claiming incompatibility.

Please help, this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Open the `209Kb` file in Notepad - is it actually a bunch of HTML and other content doing some kind of "I see you're trying to download something, click here to begin download"?  Or prompting you to login? Apart from that, there isn't much in your code telling it to stop downloading, so I suspect something else on your computer or connection - AV software, flaky firewall, or whatever...

Comment: Its all html, and quite a bit of it aha, I'm no good at the stuff myself but any helpful tips? should I use an alternative file hosting site?

Comment: Depends on what the HTML is telling you.

Comment: I honestly have no clue aha

Comment: I have a feeling its just the download page html instead of the download itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by moving my file onto zippyshare.com instead of trying to get it from dropbox.